# Php array to string conversion error with SLIM framework

Tags: php, arrays

I used a php framework to pass a variable $data to a html page the echo in loop
here is my index.php :

```
$result=$db->query('select * from test');
while ($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $data[]=$row;
}
$app->render('form.php',$data));
```

and then I display form.php

```
foreach ($this->$data as $user) {
  echo $user['id']. '-' . $user['name'].'<br>'
}
```

I get array to string conversion error, any idea ?
I tired `var_dump($this->$data);` instead of the foreach loop and I get the same error : Array to string conversion

[image]

Comment: can you show us the exact text error? and you add `var_dump($user);` just in the first line of the foreach and share with us the result please?

Answer (score 1):

maybe $this->data instead of $this->$data

```
foreach ($this->$data as $user) {
  echo $user['id']. '-' . $user['name'].'<br>'
}
```

Comment: use `$this->data` intaed of `$this->$data`, it's good idea :)